# Installing javaws through SDKMAN on MacOS to access a KVM remote host?

Tags: macos, jdk

[SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) should install the full JDK, right? Today I run `sdk install java 18.0.1.1-open` to install the OpenJDK. After resetting my Terminal, I still can't access `javaws`:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports javaws.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

But `java --version` successfully returns:

> openjdk 18.0.1.1 2022-04-22
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)

What is going on? Is `javaws` not installed through SDKMAN? I need to open a `jnlp` file to access a KVM remote host.

Answer (score 1):

> Java Web Start (JWS) was deprecated in Java 9, and starting with Java 11, Oracle removed JWS from their JDK distributions. This means that clients that have the latest version of Java installed can no longer use JWS-based applications. And since public support of Java 8 has ended in Q2/2019, companies no longer get any updates and security fixes for Java Web Start.
>
> This is why we decided to create OpenWebStart, an open source reimplementation of the Java Web Start technology. Our replacement provides the most commonly used features of Java Web Start and the JNLP standard, so that your customers can continue using applications based on Java Web Start and JNLP without any change.

Source: https://openwebstart.com/

So I installed it through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```sh
brew install --cask openwebstart
```

and then I could open the file with the installed OpenWebStart application.